# iterate/loop over all columns

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I'm new to pandas, still learning and I wanted to ask if using `iloc[:,1]` is locating the column by index, how can I get all the columns if I want to get all the columns from 1-10? Does it has to way to iterate over all the columns or can be only done using `iloc[]` one by one? Because I wanted to predict value of y (one column) with all the variables in x for eg:col[0] to col[9]. I've tried `iteritems()` beforehand but it says

> Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Code:

```
regrmodel = linear_model.LinearRegression()
print("Y train",y_train)
regrmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_test_pred = regrmodel.predict(X_test)
y_test_pred = pd.Series(y_test_pred)
y_test_pred.index = y_test.index

plt.scatter(X_test.iloc[:,9], y_test, color='red',label='Actual data')
plt.scatter(X_test.iloc[:,9], predicted_test_data, color='green',label='Predicted data')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
X_test.iloc[:,range(0,10)]
```

This gives you a dataframe with columns 0-9 and then you can process each column in a for loop.

Alternatively, you can get a name list of all columns by calling

```
X_test.columns
```

Then you can iterate the list and access each column by calling

```
X_test[your_column_name]
```

Comment: but y_test is just one column so I don't think that works?

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of how/why this addresses OP's issue to improve understanding, quality, & to add long term value so future visitors can apply this knowledge to their own issues.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a new dataframe with the first ten columns of `X_test`:

```
X_test[X_test.columns[:10]]
```